# PowerMockito cannot mock constructor for FileInputStream

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

I am trying to mock the constructor for the FileInputStream and I have the following code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FileInputStream.class)
public class DBUtilsTest {

    @Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void readTableMetadataFileNotFoundException() throws Exception {
        try {
            PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class)
                    .withParameterTypes(String.class)
                    .withArguments(Matchers.any(String.class))
                    .thenThrow(FileNotFoundException.class);

            PowerMock.replayAll();

            TableMetadata tableMeta = DBUtils
                    .readTableMetadata(path);
        } finally {
            PowerMock.verifyAll();
        }
    }
}
public class DBUtils {
    public static TableMetadata readTableMetadata(String metadataPath)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(metadataPath); 
        properties.load(is);
        .....
    }
}
```

Though, the test fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException`

It seems that the constructor isn't really mocked and the exception does not get thrown.
Can anyone give any help with this issue?

Comment: Could you post the code of  Utils.readTableMetadata(path)? Maybe it's not calling the correct constructor?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it is DBUtils.readTableMetadata(path) and the code is posted already.

Comment: `thenThrow` takes an instance of exception, not a class. And you don't need to mock the exception because `new FileInputStream(String)` will throw `FileNotFoundException` anyway if the file does not exists..

Comment: fair point, I don't necessary need to mock the exception. But it still does not work if I give an instance of an FileNotFoundException to the thenThrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that I should prepare for test the tested class, meaning DBUtils, and not the FileInputStream class.

```
@PrepareForTest(DBUtils.class)
```

some useful examples can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).